# Double-clicking on my C program compiled in VSCode for Mac "latest version" can't find the program needs to open with the open command

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm trying to run a C program created in VSCODE on my Mac and every-time I open the program from the "Finder" by double-clicking on it, the current working directory changes to my MacOs account default folder, something like /Users/joedirt/.

I try to open the file like so:

```
FILE *ptrToFile;
ptrToFile = fopen("./dataHW3.txt", "r");
```

The program runs but it does not find the files. It tries to open in another folder which is my CWD (Current Working Directory) -> /Users/joedirt/ It get this result in the terminal window.

And when I add this code:

```
char path[200];
getcwd(path, 200);
printf("Current working directory: %s\n", path);
```

I get "Current working directory: /Users/joedude"

[image]

I want the directory it looks for to be the directory where I put my build file. it's in already and where the other files it needs are. I tried setting up the task.json and launch.json for VSCode, with this option:

```
"options": {"cwd": "${fileDirname}"}
```

or even try to set it to the directory I put the build file and files I'm trying to open. But that does not change anything.

When I use the full path to where the files are in the open statement like so:

```
ptrToFile = fopen("/Users/joedirt/week3/assignment5/dataHW3.txt","r");
```

it works!

But... When I send my exe files and text files (build files) to someone else, there is no way that I know where he is going to put the files. I just want to use the path to where the file resides.

Now, I know some of you will think that I wish for things that are not possible, but because I new to C, I'm not a new programmer. I have been programming since Basic on a Texas Instrument PC in 1984. I'm just new to this version of VSCode. Then tell me why when I compile my code on different PCs or Macs, with VSCode, I don't get this problem.

Comment: If you just want an easy kludge to access files relative to where the executable is, get `argv[0]` (from the arguments passed to `main`), truncate it at the last `/` in it, and change the working directory (with `chdir`) to that.

Comment: This is not a change with the “latest version” of macOS.

Comment: @EricPostpischil , thanks Eric, I understand that is possible, but I was looking for a resolution of the problem, not a work-around. I believe it's my duty to make this the easiest for my students. They barely know C and using something like (chdir) was not part of the scope of this course and argv[0] comes much later in class. ???!!! Also, what do you mean by your second comment... Are you confirming it has nothing to do with the latest MacOS or are you asking that maybe that is an issue?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the latest version of MacOS.  Also, you are not going to find a better "solution" to this problem.  As I tried to explain elsewhere, trying to access things in the directory of the running executable is generally held to be a bad idea under Unix (and hence also Linux and AFAIK MacOS).  So the best you're going to get is a "kludge" or a "workaround".  If you want a real solution, that would be "Do not try to locate resources in the directory of the executable."  And if you want to be kind to your students, you will certainly not lead them down this rabbit hole!

Comment: @SteveSummit OK, I understand that files should be held somewhere else. Like the "Documents" folder in windows or when using Application.persistentDataPath in C#. I used to write a-lot with Swift and my files were in a sub folder of my solution, it was for Swift. If that is not good practice, then what is? I was always thought it that way and I did not see a difference between the executable location and a subfolder of it. Do you have a link to such C++ good practice about this? I have to back up my course mentor with references. Thanks for all your help Steve.

Comment: -- Sorry, I meant to say "I have to back my course with references before I present it to my mentor (Master's Professor)." Let's say for example, I have multiple files, like jpegs and so on, where would one store those in C++ solution and what software would you recommend to bundle such a solution. In my C++ class, it was really vague and not much time was spent on that Language for my bachelor, and most professors back then, didn't bother demonstrating any technique since they had a custom program that would package all of our files for them. Thanks again for your input.